# Desmanchar número com zeros

Tags: php

Gostaria de desmanchar um número contendo zeros e pegar os valores inteiros.

Exemplo:

> 0002100042000560000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Tenho esse número e preciso retirar separadamente o 21, 42 e 56.

Alguém saberia me informar como?

Comment: E se o número inteiro possuir um zero?

Comment: Não tem lógica isso. Ou você usa delimitado ou terá problemas como o @HomerSimpson disse quando valores tiverem 0.

Comment: Mesmo que você considere como números inteiros de 1~99 teria problemas ao capturar os menores que 10 com 10,20,30 e etc... para segregá-los só seria possível se considerar apenas um range de 10~99

Answer (score 5):

Com expressão regular, você consegue isso de forma trivial:

```
$text = "0002100042000560000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";

if (preg_match_all("/[^0]+/", $text, $matches)) {
    print_r($matches);
}
```

O resultado seria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 21
            [1] => 42
            [2] => 56
        )

)
```

A expressão `[^0]+` pega qualquer sequência de caracteres com tamanho mínimo de 1 que não sejam o caractere 0.

Answer (score 4):

Ta ai uma solução simples para seu problema:

```
<?php

$teste = '0002100042000560000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';

$arrayExplode = explode('0',$teste);
$arrayResultado = array_filter($arrayExplode);
print_r($arrayResultado);
```

Resultado:

```
Array ( [3] => 21 [6] => 42 [9] => 56 )
```